# Python - how do you select from variables when different conditions are met

Tags: python, variables, random, numpy

I'm wondering if anyone can help me with a python programming problem. I have 5 numbers (0,2,30,180,356) and want to select one condition randomly

```
delayVariable=[0,2,30,180,365]
delayCondition = random.choice(delayVariable)
```

each time i want to select the number at random until another condition is met. For instance when "365" has been selected 20 times, i no longer want it to select that condition and instead the random number should be generated from [0,2,30,180], and again if "30" has been selected 20 times I also want this to be excluded so the random number should be generated from [0,2,180]. I want this to continue until no numbers are left.

Thank you in advance

---

Thank you those answers are exactly what I need. The more complex problem is when another condition is met, which might occur before that number has been selected 20 times. Yet i'd still want the selection of that number to stop. For instance:

if condition1="off" then I no longer want "0" to be selected, if condition2="off" then I no longer want "2" to be selected etc....

Comment: How many numbers are there? If its just 100, just create a list holding 20x0, 20x2, etc., shuffle it, and pop elements from that list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a counter.

```
import collections
import random

delays=[0,2,30,180,365]

counter = collections.defaultdict(int)
while delays:
    condition = random.choice(delays)
    print(condition)
    counter[condition] += 1
    if counter[condition] == 20:
        delays.remove(condition)
```

The program counts how often every element from the list was choosen. The element gets removed when the threshold (here 20) is reached.

If you want to remove an element from the list based on a condition before the threshold is reached you have two options. First you could set the counter value for this condition to the threshold value. The element will be deleted by the `remove` in the code. The second - and in my opinion better approach - is to just remove the element from the list. If the element does not longer exist it can't be selected. Problem solved.

Comment: Thank you those answers are exactly what I need. The more complex problem is when another condition is met, which might occur before that number has been selected 20 times. Yet i'd still want the selection of that number to stop. For instance:

if condition1="off" then I no longer want "0" to be selected, if condition2="off" then I no longer want "2" to be selected etc....

Comment: thanks so much for your help but i can't seem to get this to work. Because this code is in a bigger loop, i want the code to remember which has been removed and only provide one number. I can only get this code to work as a separate piece which outputs all numbers. Like you suggested in your edit, i just want to permanently delete that variable once a condition is made but allow the rest of the script to continue

Comment: You have to know what happens when. Initialize the counter where you initialize the list with the data. Everything else happens in the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is equivalent to picking distinct elements from the array [twenty "365"s, twenty "30"s, ...]. We can get distinct elements from an array using `random.sample`.

```
>>> random.sample([0,2,30,180,365] * 20, 80)
[0, 2, 180, 180, 2, 0, 180, 30, 365, 365, 30, 30, 30, 365, 30, 0, 365, 365, 2, 0, 
 30, 2, 365, 30, 180, 180, 180, 0, 30, 180, 365, 180, 0, 2, 365, 0, 0, 30, 180, 30, 30, 
 2, 365, 2, 180, 30, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 30, 30, 0, 180, 2, 2, 365, 180, 365, 2, 2, 2, 365, 
 30, 30, 0, 0, 180, 30, 30, 30, 0, 365, 365, 0, 365, 30, 2, 180]
>>> collections.Counter(_) # check that we have no more than twenty "30"s, etc.
Counter({30: 20, 0: 16, 2: 15, 365: 15, 180: 14})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use them as a Dictionary

```
delayVariable={0:50,2:50,30:50,180:50,365:50}
```

so after each time there was a selection you can reduce the value until it's 0, use an if to check if it's 0 then pop it from the dict.

It's elegant solution if you want you can use `if` statements but then it will be an `if` for each delay! so it's not a clear approach but it will work.

Comment: Nice idea for a flexible approach.